# Why I can't get the search result?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple search bar which I can use to search for customer's name, telephone number, address, note, or date. I search the data from my `customer` table which contains the following fields: `id`, `name`, `telno`, `adress`, `note`, and `date`. My question is: Why I can't get the search result, even if I don't get any error message?

Here is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['search']) && !empty($_POST['search'])){
  $db =new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '1234' , 'trying');
  if($db->connect_errno) die ('Connect Error:' . $db->connect_errno);

  $stmt = $db ->prepare("select * from customer where name or note or date or telno like ?");

  if($stmt === FALSE) die("Query Error". $db ->error);

  $ara ='%'.$_POST['search'].'%';

  $stmt->bind_param("s", $ara);

  $stmt->execute();

  $res =$stmt->get_result();

  if($res -> num_rows <1) die("can't found !");

  while ($row = $res->fetch_array())
  {

    echo $row['name']. '<br/>';
    echo $row['telno']. '<br/>';
    echo $row['note']. '<br/>';
    echo $row['adress']. '<br/>';
    echo $row['date']. '<br/>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Do read the manual on SELECT https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 2):

Your query is totally wrong. You cannot test multiple values against a single paramter like you are:

```
 where name or note or date or telno like ?
            ^^      ^^      ^^
```

This is executed as

```
where (some value) or (some value) or (some value) or (some value LIKE ?)
where (t/f) or (t/f) or (t/f) or (some value like ?)
where (t/f) or (some value like ?)
```

You have to do the `like` test for EVERY value:

```
where (name LIKE ?) or (note LIKE ?) or (date LIKE ?) etc...
```

Comment: I swear Marc, you must've been part of the BBS rage in ANSI Art, way back when.

Comment: well, back in the bbs days, all I had as a 2400 baud modem with no ECC and a noisy line, so technically everything I saw was "art" of some type...

Comment: I probably still have my Toshiba laptop with 2400 baud modem kicking around somewhere. I may have used it for a doorstop at some point too, or landfill; *maybe the dog knows*.

Comment: Not to mention those funky connection sounds (that sometimes lasted for a minute or more) *"gey, pssht, berrr.. gah beeeep, sshhh, bahhhh"*. Cable's boring (in more ways than one).

Comment: Thank you for your help. My new query is like you said. But still i can't get result

Comment: i realized that my html code wrong , i fixed it and now my new issue ; whatever i write in search box i get everything which registered databese not i want,even if i write thing that is not at databese..

Comment: that's because of your sql problem. you're pasing in a "non-false" value, so `true or anything` evalues to `true`, which makes EVERYTHING match.